# dll dependency issue in windows with msvc runtime

Tags: windows, dll, msvcrt

I am trying to run a program that depends on Matlab 2010 binaries. Those depend on msvc80 dlls.

It worked fine a couple of days ago. Then I installed a new version of Matlab, and all hell broke loose. Note that I am still trying to run the same program depending on the same Matlab binaries.
I have :

- Installed and uninstalled the latest msvc 2005 redistributable package.
- Removed all occurence of Matlab 2014 from my path.

When I run dependency walker, it finds MSVCR80.DLL, but not always, I wonder if it is looking for another version?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3RCr.jpg

I have tried copying the version it finds in the winsxs folder, but it leads to a runtime error saying I am trying to load the C runtime library the wrong way...

Where should I go now?

Comment: Yes, it probably is looking for another version.  Depending on how we are supposed to interpret "all hell".  Don't use depends, it is inept at detecting these side-by-side deployed DLLs.  Use the Windows event log for details.  Call MathWorks if you need support.

Comment: Hum, the thing is there is no side-by-side dll here, Matlab uses vc_redist package. I uninstalled all other vc_redist packages, but everything remains in the winsxs folder. I will check the event log !